# How to check what is breaking automatic updates kernel when use apt upgrade or dist-upgrade？

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

My current system version is 18.04 LTS, ​​kernel 4.15.0-45-generic.
Due to [CVE-2019-11477](https://usn.ubuntu.com/4017-1/), I want to update the kernel to the fixed version linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic.
I tried `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and nothing happened. But when I use `apt search linux-image-4.15.0-52`, this kernel exists in the official repo. Then I installed it manually.

According to Karel's answer, I tested it on the new VPS, and both of them can update the kernel.So I think it is a file in the system is corrupted.
How to check it?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/username# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                               
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/nginx-mainline/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                   
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                                                                    
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                  
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (110 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt search linux-image-4.15.0-52
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic/bionic-updates 4.15.0-52.56 amd64
  Signed kernel image generic

linux-image-4.15.0-52-lowlatency/bionic-updates 4.15.0-52.56 amd64
  Signed kernel image lowlatency
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

new vps with 18.04 LTS

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)

root@vultr:~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-52 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-52-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:


root@vultr:~# apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-52 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-52-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
```

`apt-cache policy linux-image-generic`

```
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt-cache policy linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.15.0.52.54
  Version table:
     4.15.0.52.54 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.15.0.51.53 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     4.15.0.20.23 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You're missing the required metapackages.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something you did on your system removed the **metapackage** that makes those upgrades "just work".

The `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` packages *track* the latest released kernel version for your system - 4.15.0 - and you need to have them installed to get prompted for upgrades.

`sudo apt install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` should be sufficient to do this.  This should also pull in the version of the kernel package you are after, though it seems whatever mirror you're on doesn't have -52.56 but -52.54.

Answer (score 3):

Linux kernel 4.15.0-52 is in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. Update the software in Ubuntu 18.04 and it will update the kernel to 4.15.0-52. This is how I did it (I didn't use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`).

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

Results of `apt policy linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic` after updating the software in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ apt policy linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic:
  Installed: 4.15.0-52.56
  Candidate: 4.15.0-52.56
  Version table:
 *** 4.15.0-52.56 500
```

Reboot Ubuntu to boot with the newly installed kernel. Then the results of `uname -a` will show that Ubuntu 18.04 is using the latest installed kernel version.

Comment: I tested it on a new vps, as you said. but the first thing I tried was apt update &apt upgrade.

Comment: Just a typo, I reverted to 4.15.0-45, then re-attempt and added the output to the question.  Maybe something is broken on my system?

Comment: @maP1EbluE show the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` please. As an edit to your question.

Comment: @maP1EbluE the issue is those generic metapackages aren't installed.  You need thsoe to get "continued" updates to the kernel version.  See my answer.